# Can't get paint function to update in simple pong game

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, pong

I'm a relatively inexperienced Java programmer when it comes to graphics. I'm trying to make a simple pong game to learn more about how graphics are done in Java.

In the program, the left paddle (the only paddle thus far implemented) should move up 5 pixels when 'W' is pressed on the keyboard. According to the console, it is recognizing that the key is being pressed, and it is updating a variable that represents the y-coordinate for the left paddle accordingly. However, the paddle's location isn't actually being updated on the screen.

Help?

Game class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {
    
    static int WIDTH = 500;
    static int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window();
    }
    
    public static void window() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(new Panel());
        frame.addKeyListener(new Panel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Panel class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    
    int leftPaddlePos = 100;
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(75, leftPaddlePos, 15, 100);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("W pressed");
            leftPaddlePos = leftPaddlePos + 5;
            System.out.println(leftPaddlePos);
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
```

Don't call your class `Panel`. There is an AWT class with that name so it is confusing. Your class name should be more descriptive. Maybe something like `PongPanel`.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
```

Don't override paint(...);

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Custom painting in Swing is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`.

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
```

Don't use above code to paint the background of the panel. Instead, you just use:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

So in the constructor of your class you can invoke `setBackground(...)` to set the desired background color.

> However, the paddle's location isn't actually being updated on the screen.

```
leftPaddlePos = leftPaddlePos + 5;
```

You update the position, but you haven't told the component that a property of the class has changed, so it doesn't know it needs to paint itself again.

You should not change the property of the class in the listener. Instead you should have a method like `adjustLeftPaddlePosition(int value)`

The method would be:

```
public void adjustLeftPaddlePostion(int value)
{
    leftPaddlePos = leftPaddlePos + value;
    repaint();
}
```

Then in the KeyListener you would use:

```
adjustLeftPaddlePosition(5);
```

Also, you should not be using a KeyListener. Instead you should be using "Key Bindings" Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.